# configfile-based Generic GUI

Tags: c++, user-interface, configuration-files

I'm supposed to develop a simple GUI framework (C++, wxWidgets) which is configurable only by means of a ini / config file and I'm wondering if there is any such thing out there already.

Maybe it's helpful to give a (very simple) example:

let's say my config file looks like this:

```
menu-item = file-dialog
menu-item = execute(sh ~home/myFooBarProgramm param1 param2)
```

When it parses the config I want that it creates an GUI with two menu-items, one that opens a file-dialog and another one that runs the specified program.

So, my question is: is there any piece of software that can do such or similar things out there already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should do it QML, here are some examples and demos: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdeclarativeexamples.html